# How can I implement increase or decrease quantity till countInStock of my my e-commerce project with the below code?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, e-commerce

I have made same thing using form Form.control .
Here is the code and [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meaw1.png)

```
    {product.countInStock > 0 && (
                    <ListGroupItem>
                      <Row>
                        <Col>Qty</Col>
                        <Form.Control
                          as="select"
                          value={qty}
                          onChange={(e) => setQty(e.target.value)}
                        >
                          {[...Array(product.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                            <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                              {x + 1}
                            </option>
                          ))}
                        </Form.Control>
                      </Row>
                    </ListGroupItem>
                  )}
```

but I want the same thing in input tag format [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPpan.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                    <input
                      type="number"
                      value={qty}
                      onChange={(e) => setQty(e.target.valueAsNumber)}
                      min="0"
                      max={product.countInStock}
                    />
```